# Why does the Option() constructor create an empty option even though the condition is not met?

Tags: javascript

I get a list of options from the backend and I iterate through the list and I want to create options only for elements whose value is not `some_string` or empty string:

```
const selectElement = document.getElementById("my_select");

const optionsList = // data as Object from backend;

Object.keys(optionsList).forEach(key => {
    if ( (optionsList[key]['value'] === "some_string") || (optionsList[key]['value'] === "")){
        console.log("empty or some_string");
    } else {
        console.log(optionsList[key]['value']);
        selectElement[key] = new Option(optionsList[key]['value'],key);
    }
});
```

I even console log the values, and I get the values logged in the correct order so I get something like the following in the console:

```
>empty or some_string
>some_val_1
>some_val_2
>empty or some_string
```

But instead of skipping the creation of the `<option>` element, it creates empty options in the order of the logged data (Just made sure the empty options do come from that):

```
<option></option>
<option value="some_val_1">some_val_1</option>
<option value="some_val_2">some_val_2</option>
<option></option>
```

Example:

```js
const optionsList = {
    "1" : {value: 'some_string'},
    "2" : {value: 'some_val_1'},
    "3" : {value: 'some_val_2'},
    "4" : {value: ''}
}

const selectElement = document.getElementById("my_select");

Object.keys(optionsList).forEach(key => {
    if ( (optionsList[key]['value'] === "some_string") || (optionsList[key]['value'] === "")){
        console.log("empty or some_string");
    } else {
        console.log(optionsList[key]['value']);
        selectElement[key] = new Option(optionsList[key]['value'],key);
    }
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<select id='my_select'>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Why?

Comment: Can you make a [mcve], please? Especially with some sample value for `optionsList`.

Comment: "*it creates empty options in the order of the logged data*" - it doesn't for me. I get `<option></option><option></option><option value="2">some_val_1</option><option value="3">some_val_2</option>` in your snippet - the two empty ones come first. And that actually confirms the guess from my answer.

Comment: Ok it's weird that's the closest I could come to reproduce my issue but in my case it does it by order. I think that it's because I am using another package on top of the `<option>` so it can be that it is the same ( I use a JS package that hides the `<option>`s and use stylized `<div>`s that correspond to the `<option>`s, and probably re-order them by name) , so you seem to be correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are you using `selectElement[key] = …` instead of [`selectElement.add(…)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/add). This is equivalent to `selectElement.options[key] = …`, and [creates as many empty `<option>` elements as are missing before the given index](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-dom-interfaces.html#dom-htmloptionscollection-setter). Assigning to `selectElement["2"]` in particular creates empty options for indices `0` and `1`.

```js
const optionsList = {
    "1" : {value: 'some_string'},
    "2" : {value: 'some_val_1'},
    "3" : {value: 'some_val_2'},
    "4" : {value: ''}
}

const selectElement = document.getElementById("my_select");

for (const [key, {value}] of Object.entries(optionsList)) {
    if (value === "some_string" || value === "") {
        console.log("empty or some_string");
    } else {
        console.log(value);
        selectElement.add(new Option(value, key));
//                   ^^^^
    }
}
console.log(selectElement.innerHTML);
```

```html
<select id='my_select'></select>
```

Comment: You seem to be correct, then it means I should not use the `Options()` constructor at all right? They are 2 different things - either use `Options()` or `add()`

Comment: `add` still takes a `new Option` as its argument. Nothing to change there. I'd be happy to provide a full snippet if you could add a [mcve] to your question.

Comment: I added a snippet, thanks

Comment: you are correct, thank you. And my mistake was also thinking that it was added by order. But I was using a JS package that customize the multiple select and hides the actual `<option>`s with stylized `<div>`s and also as it seem it re-orders it. But the underlying `<option>` were still as in my snippet above